# converting a .net durandal SPA from http to https

Tags: .net, durandal-2.0, single-page-application

i have a .NET Single page application (Durandal).

i want to convert it from HTTP to HTTPS in order to make it secure and add the certificates thing.

how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IIS, go to Features view of your application in IIS panel, then click on SSL settings.

Check the "Requires SSL" checkbox.

You can leave the default Ignore for Client certificates checkbox and change later if required.

Then also in IIS, click on the server (top level) then in features view, double click "Server Certificates"

From there, either import a certificate you already have, create a test self-signed certificate or buy a new certificate from a verfied certifcate provider.

Then in your website, click on bindings... you can bind https usually to the default port 443.

You can also configure this more through the configuration editor in IIS features view if required - e.g. the access level in webserver in the drop down can be set to https only.

To check your changes have worked, you can browse to your site with IE, then click on the lock near the address bar. This will show the details of your certificate.

Regards, Rob

Comment: the Require SSL is disabled for my site ??? it says the site does not have a secure binding (HTTPS) and cannot accept SSL connections.

Comment: In IIS, at the site level, click on Bindings in the features view then you can add a binding for https first.

Comment: Bindings is on right hand side in action pane. Select this and then create a binding with type https.

Comment: You can also select your ssl certificate in that dialog

Comment: stuck again mate, now when i run the application from my IDE, it says unable to start debugging on webserver. The underlining connection was closed. An unexpected error occurred on a send.

Comment: There is a setting you need to add to your web.config for debugging. Are you using IISExpress or local debugging through the IDE?

Comment: local IIS debugging for now, i have already added this in my web config

<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />

Comment: So you can access the site OK through a client browser but when you run it through Visual Studio you get this issue right?

Comment: actually the website isnt deployed yet, i am just developing it and its only on my IDE

Comment: Hi, this link may help: